# UWP Make phone call not allowed in China, how to prevent deployment in China?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

In my app I am trying to make it possible for the user to push a button and make a phone call

At the moment I was using this

```
if (phoneCallStore != null)
{
   var lineGuid = await phoneCallStore.GetDefaultLineAsync();

   if (lineGuid != Guid.Empty)
   {
      var phoneLine = await PhoneLine.FromIdAsync(lineGuid);

      if (phoneLine != null && phoneLine.CanDial)
      {
         phoneLine.Dial(number, name);
      }
   }
}
```

But I was rejected by Microsoft as they say

```
Phone Call In Restricted Market: 2000.5 Phone Call In Restricted Market
The phonecall capability cannot be used in the application since it targets restricted markets (China).
```

***EDIT***

I tried removing China from markets, which fixed the problem. 
But can I somehow, check if the user is from China?

Comment: Did you ensure that you added the [device capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) for Phone calls in your package's manifest?

Comment: Did you try excluding China from the list of target markets when you submitted your app?

Comment: I have submitted it now and excluded China. Now we will wait and see, what they are saying

Comment: Review the `Market` selection : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/define-pricing-and-market-selection

Comment: and use protocol activation with call:<phonenyumber> ?

Comment: @DaveSmits Why use protocol activation instead of PhoneCallManager?

Comment: @Jason Thanks for your help :D It fixed my problem. Can you put an answer on my question, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The phonecall capability cannot be used in the application since it targets restricted markets (China).

Then when you submit your app you should exclude China from the list of target markets.